# Bundler's rake release with geminabox?

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler

Is there a way to configure bundler so that when I do `rake release` it would submit the gem to my own gem server (a [gem in a box](https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox) instance) rather than to rubygems?

Ideally this configuration would be something I can omit from my git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubygems is actually hard-coded into bundler and I've found only one way around it.

The following monkeypatch should get you what you want:

```
module Bundler
  class GemHelper
    protected
    def rubygem_push(path)
      if Pathname.new("~/.gem/nexus").expand_path.exist?
        sh("gem nexus '#{path}'")
        Bundler.ui.confirm "Pushed #{name} #{version} to https://<your-url-here>/."
      else
        raise "Your Nexus credentials aren't set. Run `gem nexus #{path}` to push your gem and set credentials."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above is for Nexus instead of Geminabox, but the concept should apply to either.

As far as omitting it from git, I'm afraid we're out of luck. However, you can share this appropriately between projects so it will only have to be checked into one place rather than many. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

i made a dependency free gem for this which imitates the geminabox http post request and overwrites bundlers rake release with rake release:inabox

https://github.com/dfherr/geminabox-release

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the task which uploads the gem to rubygems, that's less intrusive then the solution provided by JohnIV, though the concept is the same.

```
Rake::Task['release:rubygem_push'].clear
namespace :release do
    task :rubygem_push do
      version = ModuleName::VERSION
      name = 'module_name'
      cmd = "gem nexus pkg/#{name}-#{version}.gem"
      puts `#{cmd} 2>&1`
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `'bundler_geminabox'` to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'bundler_geminabox'
end
```

Then, in your rakefile, instead of requiring `'bundler/gem_tasks'`:

```
require 'bundler_geminabox/gem_tasks'
```

You don't need to add any tasks to the rakefile; you will automatically get `rake build`, `rake install`, and `rake release`, the last of which uploads to the server listed in `~/.gem/geminabox`. Otherwise, the behavior is the same as the equivalent tasks provided by `bundler/gem_tasks`.

Gem on Github: https://github.com/joshkrueger/bundler_geminabox

Comment: An example would really save this answer.