# Rake's release task for Gem deployment to a geminabox server hangs

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I used Bundler's `gem` command to create a Gem skeleton as the basis for my Gem.

I'm attempting to deploy the resulting Gem to a server that uses [geminabox](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox).

I can manually publish a Gem using `geminabox`'s client functionality:

```
$ gem inabox pkg/lorem-0.1.1.gem
Pushing lorem-0.1.1.gem to http://gem.domain.tld/...
Gem lorem-0.1.1.gem received and indexed.
```

However, Rake's `release` task hangs.

```
$ rake release
lorem 0.1.1 built to pkg/lorem-0.1.1.gem.
Tagged v0.1.1.
Pushed git commits and tags.
[hangs here]
```

Does the `bundler/gem_tasks` (which is added to the `Rakefile` by the scaffolding code) support `geminabox`?

Looks like I can use the [bundler_geminabox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24432027/134367) Gem, but it would be nice to know if `bundler/gem_tasks` should work.

Answer (score 0):

[bundler_geminabox](https://github.com/joshkrueger/bundler_geminabox) solution:

Add gem as a development dependency to the `.gemspec`:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler_geminabox"
```

Increment PATCH in `version.rb`:

```
0.1.2
```

Commit to Git:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'using bundler_geminabox'
```

Reference in Rakefile (removing `bundler/gem_tasks`):

```
require 'bundler_geminabox/gem_tasks'
```

Run rake task:

```
$ rake release
lorem 0.1.2 built to pkg/lorem-0.1.2.gem.
Tagged v0.1.2.
Pushed git commits and tags.
Pushed lorem 0.1.2 to your geminabox server.
```